# Сделать превьюшки из изображения на сервере

Tags: php, slim

Собственно, хочу сделать из изображения, которое хранится в непубличной папке проекта превьюшку с меньшим разрешением и качеством. Проблема в том, что не могу нагуглить ничего путного. Как мне видится - необходимо как-то открыть изображение и сохранить его с другим разрешением и качеством. Проблема именно в первом - как его так открыть то? Еще возможно как-то фреймворк slim поможет в этом, а то я в документации подобного найти не могу.

Comment: https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь GD. http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php
Вам не обязательно сохранять изображение в меньшем качестве, Вы можете получать его динамически по какому-либо роуту с передачей например имени файла либо id пользователя, если подразумевается аватар, например. Там есть функции для изменения размера без изменения пропорций, да чего там только нет, собственно. Пару-тройку лет назад я сам делал то же самое, что Вы хотите сделать, и юзал для этого именно GD. Удачи

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю и этот вариант.